# Swift: Find date in array that is closest in time

Tags: swift, date

This is my first time developing in swift (macOS command line application).

I am iterating over all jpeg files in a folder, take those that don't have GPS info in the EXIF data and find for each one another image *with* GPS data that is closest in time (Exif Timestamp). Then I want to copy the GPS data from the image.

I have a struct with a filename (String), date (Date) and GPS (Dictionary) and created an array for all the files (I didn't paste the function `getFiles()` here).

```
struct stFile {
    var name : String
    var date : Date
    var gps : [String : AnyObject]?
}
```

Then I sort the array by the date field:

```
var files = getFiles(folder: "files://FolderToJpegs/")
var filesSorted = files.sorted(by: { $0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending })
```

All I could come up with until now is a function that finds files where the date is exactly the same (Skip files where the name is equal because that's the same file we are iterating over currently):

```
for file in filesSorted {
    if (file.gps == nil) {
        if let closesdate = filesSorted.first(where: { $0.date.compare(file.date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending && $0.name != file.name }) {
            print("The closest date to \(file.date) is \(closesdate.date).")
        }
    }
}
```

As I'm new to swift I was wondering if there is already an easy way in version 4 to accomplish this. One way I guess would be to nest another iteration within the first one and calculate time differences.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Okay, so far I came up with a solution that calculates the time differences between one element and each of the others which have gps data (.gps != nil):

```
for (index, _) in filesSorted.enumerated()
{
    if filesSorted[index].gps == nil
    {
        var timeDiffPrev = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        var closestFile:stFile?

        for fileWithGPS in filesSorted
        {
            if(filesSorted[index].name != fileWithGPS.name && fileWithGPS.gps != nil)
            {
                let timeDiff = abs(filesSorted[index].date.timeIntervalSince(fileWithGPS.date))
                if(timeDiff < timeDiffPrev)
                {
                    closestFile = fileWithGPS
                }
                timeDiffPrev = timeDiff
            }
        }
        if(closestFile != nil)
        {
            filesSorted[index].gps = closestFile?.gps
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "closest" you mean "latest" then here is my solution for you:

First some extensions that will help us:

```
extension Collection where Element: Hashable {
    var orderedSet: [Element]  {
        var set = Set<Element>()
        return compactMap { set.insert($0).inserted ? $0 : nil }
    }
}
```

Thanks to this extension we will remove duplicates from collection.
But now we need your struct to conform to `Hashable` protocol.

```
extension stFile: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: stFile, rhs: stFile) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
}
```

Thanks to above we can create function like this:

```
func getLatest() -> stFile? {
    return files.orderedSet.filter({$0.gps != nil}).sorted(by: {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending}).first
}
```

where:

- `orderedSet` remove duplicates (files with the same name)
- `filter` remove files without gps data
- `sorted` is sorting whats left from previous operations (and because `orderedSet` and `filter` was used
  before, it probably has less files to sort)

---

EDIT:

At first I have misunderstood the question. I've hope that it is what you meant:

```
func copyGPS() -> [stFile] {
    let uniqueFiles = files.orderedSet.sorted(by: {$0.date.compare($1.date) == .orderedDescending})
    var filesWithGPS : [stFile] = []
    for file in uniqueFiles {
        if file.gps == nil {
            let gps = uniqueFiles.filter({$0.gps != nil && $0.date > file.date}).first?.gps
            filesWithGPS.append(stFile(name: file.name, date: file.date, gps: gps))
        } else {
            filesWithGPS.append(file)
        }
    }
    return filesWithGPS
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. By closest I mean the item for which .date is closest to the one we are currently iterating over (See my answer). But thank you for your input. I'll definitely have a look at it!

Comment: Now when i read your question again, I see that I totally misunderstood it. Sorry :/
And i think that it would be better if you update your question with code from your answer instead of posting it ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time anyway. As I'm new to swift, every insight is helpful. Put my answer as an edit to the question now.

Comment: @tzippy, I've updated my answer also. It's probably another way of what you have already done. Not sure if better. Just different ;)